# What is a good way to change behavior of a function in a certain context? (Python)

Tags: python, monkeypatching, contextmanager

For example, we have built-in function "open". I want to slightly modify a method of a library, which uses this function, and change the way "open" works.
How to do it properly?
The only thing comes to my mind is to do something like this:

```
old_open = open
open = lambda: print('I was modified!')
some_function(...)
open = old_open
```

It feels ok, but probably there is a more appropriate and common way to do this, which I don't know?
Thank you!

Comment: See https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#the-patchers ...

Comment: But is it okay to use unittest functions in your main code?
It feels kind of wrong.

Comment: Is it okay to modify a library or builtin function in your main code? It also feels kind of wrong. :D

Comment: you should monkey-patch the module, i.e. `import foo` then `foo.open = lambda : print("i was modified")` note doing just `open = whatever` won't affect anything in `foo.some_func` that uses `open`, you have to shadow builtins in *that* module's global namespace

Comment: What you are doing is already hacky, there really isn't a non-hackey way to do it

Comment: Probably you are right. Thank you for your advice.

Comment: the thing with `unittest.mock.patch` is that it already implements the context-manager protocol and various other ways that will automatically clean up after itself. if you *are* going to do this, I would probably just use that